# JMeter - Extract data from response with condition (JSON)

Tags: json, jmeter

I need to extract specific value from JSON response (or text) with a condition (another JSON value):

I have this response:

```
{
    "availabilityPercentage": "0.7713",
    "availability": [
        {
            "date": "2021-03-05",
            "estimators": [
                {
                    "skills": [
                        "Non-Driveable"
                    ],
                    "estimatorId": "99999999-0000-0000-9999-000000000002",
                    "timeSlots": [
                        {
                            "timeFrom": "08:00",
                            "isAvailable": false,
                            "timeTo": "08:30",
                            "slot": "MjAyMS0wMy0wNSUwODowMDowMCUwODozMDowMA"
                        },
                        {
                            "timeFrom": "08:30",
                            "isAvailable": true,
                            "timeTo": "09:00",
                            "slot": "MjAyMS0wMy0wNSUwODozMDowMCUwOTowMDowMA"
                        },
                        {
                            "timeFrom": "09:00",
                            "isAvailable": false,
                            "timeTo": "09:30",
                            "slot": "MjAyMS0wMy0wNSUwOTowMDowMCUwOTozMDowMA"
                        }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

And I want to extract only "slot" value when "isAvailable" is true.

How can I do it with JMeter?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries which is probably the most powerful way of getting data from JSON responses

Example JMESPath query:

```
 availability[*].estimators[*].timeSlots[?isAvailable==`true`].slot | [0] | [0]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T that also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below, use a JSON extractor and put this condition.

`$..[?(@.isAvailable == true)].slot`

[image]

Also please check your JSON is not formatted correctly